# Spring boot: @Value having issues with bean defined in dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application, say A, which has a bean defined in xml:

```xml
<bean class="com.learning.MyBean" name="myBean">
    <property name="maxAngle" value="360" ></property>
</bean>
```

Bean is:

```java
public class MyBean {

    @Value("${maxAngle}")
    public void setMaxAngle(double maxAngle) {
        ....
    }
}
```

When I run A independently, all is fine. But when I include it as dependency in another spring boot application, then I get error related to injection of maxAngle:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'maxAngle' in value "${maxAngle}"
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Try defining the property maxAngle in the main  jar's application.properties.

Comment: I found this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring#usage) from Baeldung. The only difference I see is the `id` parameter. There is also a [short example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-properties/src/main/resources/configForDbProperties.xml).

Comment: show the `properties.` or `yml` file config file ?

Comment: You're applying two separate ways of injecting the `maxAngle` property into your bean at the same time.  I've never seen this done before.  The `@Value` annotation is not needed if you are creating your bean with the indicated XML file.  The `@Value` annotation just needs there to be a Spring Environment property defined named `maxAngle`.  You're getting the error because there isn't a property defined with that name.  There are a variety of ways of defining such a property, one being to put a definition of it in your `application.properties` file, as @UmeshSanwal says.

Comment: Yes, it worked after defining the property in properties file. Jar A is a legacy project and now I wonder how it worked earlier, or may be it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Value annotation is used to bind properties defined in application.properties or application.yaml.

Try adding maxAngle=360 to application.properties or application.yaml and remove it from bean XML defination